# SSIS Flat File destination add trailing spaces to columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS development. I am developing a SSIS package which executes a stored procedure and then outputs the result to a flat file.

I have a requirement wherein I need to have columns of fixed size, so if the length a value for a particular column is lesser than the expected length I need to pad or fill it with spaces so that the length is matched.

From what I researched it seems like introducing a custom script component as transformation can do this for me.

It would be great if someone can suggest if that is the only way to achieve this or are there any better alternatives that I am just missing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you create a Flat File Connection, you have the option of having Fixed Width, doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: @FLICKER The issue I have is that the size of the column in DB is for instance 10 and I want the its size to be 50 in the flat file.I need to fill out that many space characters so that its size in the flat file will be 50.

Comment: let me add an answer to explain

Answer (score 2):

When creating Flat File Connection, you can specify the "Fixed Width" option.

Then in advanced section, you can specify the size for each field. SSIS, will add space to each field to reach the specified size.

Change the `InputColumnWidth` and `OutputColumnWidth` as needed

[image: Configure the Advance Section]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I had tried this previously but the problem is since the size of the column in the SQL DB is less it is not allowing me to increase it here.

Comment: Just like @Flicker said, but also change the data type of each column to DT_STR (or DT_WSTR, as appropriate). Everything has to be character data to allow the space padding.

Comment: @EricBrandt It doesn't allow me to change the size, once I change it somehow gets set back to the original length.I suspect this is because the actual length of the column in DB is small.

Comment: Including the output column? That's the one that's going to set up your flat file. The input size is determined by the actual data, but you should be able to configure the output.

Comment: Yes I tried to change the size in the output column and it somehow sets it back to the original one.However, I achieved it using script component transformation.I just want to check if there are any other simple alternatives to achieve this.Thanks